# Is there a way to setup Linked Resources relative to the .project file?

Tags: eclipse, version-control, project, relative-path

We have a Flash Builder (which is based on Eclipse) project that pulls source from different locations, included in the source control in which the project is. As per our organization requirements, the source code is present in directories not directly under the project directory. Initially we had the problem that all paths to the linked resources were absolute and did not work on other machines with different paths.

Right now, the solution we have for this is to set up a Linked Resource Path Variable that points to the root of the working folder. All other locations are based on that, so we can include source from folders like

```
${WORKING_BASE}/library1
${WORKING_BASE}/library2
```

The problem with this solution is that everyone that pulls the project has to set the WORKING_BASE variable correctly before opening the project for it to work. My question is, is there a way to make the Linked Resources relative to the location of the .project file? That would be ideal.

Answer (score 46):

It is possible since Eclipse 3.6 (Helios)

Open the project properties and goto Resources > Linked Resources > Path Variables.

There you can create a new variable relative to an existing one. For instance: 
Name: MY_SOURCE_FOLDER
Location: ${PROJECT_LOC}\..\src

This will add a new Path variable to your .project file with a value like:

```
$%7BPARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC%7D/src
```

meaning `${PARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC}/src`, where the `1` means the parent directory 1 times above PROJECT_LOC.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this answer. This works... They should add this to Eclipse Help Page

Comment: I was getting mad about this - thanks for this nice explanation. Of course Sébastien spoke about the same thing, but you described it better :)

Comment: @tommyd , no Sebastien didn't talk about adding a new variable, you can just use to those (quite cryptic IMHO) references directly in links. Just what I wanted

Comment: Thanks a ton bro. This answer is still valid for Luna. Saved me a ton of headache.

Answer (score 31):

With eclipse 3.7, giving this path :

```
C:\projects\workspace\project1
C:\projects\workspace\project2
```

Within project1 you can do :

```
PROJECT_LOC => C:\projects\workspace\project1
PARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC => C:\projects\workspace
PARENT-2-PROJECT_LOC => C:\projects\
PARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC\project2 => C:\projects\workspace\project2
```

Comment: I prefer this answer, simpler case, the examples make things clear (I think the actual feature is quite cryptic)

Comment: A better explanation can be found here: http://taglist.blogspot.fi/2011/08/eclipse-tricks-relative-paths-in-linked.html

Comment: Thanks a ton for this answer. This works... They should add this to Eclipse Help Page

Answer (score 0):

Use ${PROJECT_LOC} instead of ${WORKING_BASE}

Like:

${PROJECT_LOC}/library1

${PROJECT_LOC}/library2

Since project location is the base of the current project you can add relative path followed by it.