# Organizing Git submodules to share platform-generic src and tests between platform-specific Eclipse projects in separate repos

Tags: java, eclipse, git, git-submodules

I have a cross-mobile-platform project that I am trying have platform-specific Android and BlackBerry Eclipse projects in separate repos use a Git submodule that contains J2ME platform-generic src and test code.

Here is the intended layout:

```
team-lib-j2me
| - src (platform generic source code)
|   | - ...
| - test
    | - src (platform generic source code)
        | - ...

team-lib-android
| - team-lib-j2me (git submodule)
| - lib (Eclipse Android project)
|   | - AndroidManifest.xml
|   | - src (platform specific)
|   | - ...
| - test  (Eclipse Android Project)
    | - AndroidManifest.xml
    | - src (platform specific)
    | - ...

team-lib-blackberry
| - team-lib-j2me (git submodule)
| - lib (Eclipse BB Project)
|   | - BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml
|   | - src (platform specific)
|   | - ...
| - test (Eclipse BB Project)
    | - BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml
    | - src (platform specific)
    | - ...
```

I cannot seem to find a clean and simple way to:

1. Get either of the Eclipse "lib" projects to source link to the relative path "../team-lib-j2me/src"
2. Get either of the Eclipse "test" projects to source link to the relative path "../team-lib-j2me/test/src"

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it: [Is there a way to setup Linked Resources relative to the .project file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000039/is-there-a-way-to-setup-linked-resources-relative-to-the-project-file)

I just created a new path variable "TEAM_LIB_J2ME"="${PROJECT_LOC}..\team-lib-j2me", and then created "Link Source"s to:

- "team-lib-j2me-src" = TEAM_LIB_J2ME\src
- "team-lib-j2me-test-src" = TEAM_LIB_J2ME\test\src